# Sending unhashed Devise reset_password_token in custom email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

I'm using Devise 3.5 in my Rails 4.2 app. I've overridden all of the stock emails with custom HTML emails. Because of how I've designed the email delivery code, it's impossible for the email templates to have access to the hashed version of a token, such as the `reset_password_token`.

The problem I'm having is that the email template only has access to the unhashed token that is stored in the database. I've tried using the unhashed token from the database in my email template, but when a user clicks the link, Devise's `PasswordsController#update` calls `resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)`. [Devise::Recoverable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L128) then unhashes the token and tries to find the user. This fails because the unhashed token doesn't match the token in the database (because the token was already unhashed to begin with).

My question is three-part:

1. What are the security implications of sending the unhashed token in emails such as the password reset email?
2. I'm assuming that sending the unhashed token is a bad idea. If so, can I get around this problem by overriding `PasswordsController#create` so that I can intercept the hashed and unhashed tokens and save both to the database, therefore making the hashed token available to my mailer code? Are there security implications I should be aware of before attempting this approach?
3. Is there some way I can take the unhashed token and hash it before rendering my email template so that I can avoid a hacky workaround such as saving it to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are incorrect.  The unhashed token is safe to send in an email, but unsafe to store in the DB.  This is so that someone with access to your DB can't reconstruct the password reset URL.

So you want the email to have access only to the unhashed token.

For a more detailed discussion, see the "Store digested tokens in the database" at http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/

Comment: I see, so I'm mixing up hashed vs unhashed. I still have the same problem though. The shortened (unhashed) token is what should be in the email, because Devise tries to hash that and then match the output with what's in the database.

Comment: Edited to link to a reference

Comment: It should be available in the view as `@token`, but you said that you redesigned it, so without knowing the details of your redesign, I can't say how you can get `@token` into the scope where you need it

Comment: Right, `@token` isn't available in the scope of my email code because the email code is a background job that's designed to process a lot of different types of emails, not just Devise emails.

Comment: When you queue the job, you'll need to pass `@token`.  This obviously isn't ideal since it defeats the purpose of keeping `@token` out of the database, because it's still there in its unhashed form, somewhere in your database or on your redis server (depending which backend ActiveJob is using).  However, it's there for a much shorter time--just longer enough to dequeue the job and send the email, rather than until the user clicks on the password reset link in the email.

Comment: That's ultimately what I ended up doing is refactoring the job to accept the `@token`. Seems to work fine now. Thanks!